# Array operations in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

Is there a way to perform arithmetic operations such as average or max/mean over a set of array elements, that are loaded into an ArrayController or an ObjectController - this arithmetic operation would be computed again  when the array is updated.

Also, how do we obtain the last object from the array in a controller and have the template display this last element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember does not have specialized functions like mean and avg. You could easily implement it using a computed property, observing the elements of the array. This will give you exactly what you want: recomputed when the array is updated.

To display the last object, you could use [this](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html#property_lastObject)

Comment: Retrieving the last object inside the ArrayController is somewhat convoluted as in this.get('model').get('lastObject').get('name'); where name is a property of a record in the store.

Comment: you could simplify it using this.get('model.lastObject.name'). And if you use an ArrayController or ObjectController, you can do away with model: this.get('lastObject.name')

Comment: this.get('model.lastObject.name') works. I'm using the ArrayController, this.get('lastObject.name') is undefined.                  Here's how the controller is set up in the route -   setupController: function(controller, <modelname>) {
        controller.set('model', <modelname>);
    },
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        controller.set('content', model);
    }

Comment: Could you set up a fiddle please!